using :focus without a button or link?
Is it possible to use :focus without having a button or link to focus something? I'm trying to put the code into a game which "doesn't allow" buttons and when I try using <a href="#" class="button"> (as seen in the code below) it just gives me a message if I want to be sent to this link. I'm wondering if there's anything i can do to "bypass" the message i get with the link or simply use something else.
What I want is to have something that makes my content show up when clicked and disappear when clicking somewhere on the screen.


.morebuttonbox {
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, #ecd0ff, white 1px, transparent 0, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-color: #fcf8f8;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 260px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
}

.button {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  border: 1px ridge black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
  position: absolute
}

.contentbox2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 130px;
  width: 301px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 190px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.morebuttonbox:has(.button:focus)~.contentbox2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}
<div class="morebuttonbox">
  <a href="#" class="button">
      more
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="contentbox2">
  <div class="byi">
    <span style="background-color:#ecd0ff;color:#7d6f85;padding:1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px; border-radius: 3px;   border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;">byi</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text ...

    <div class="dni">
      <span style="background-color:#ecd0ff;color:#7d6f85;padding:1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px; border-radius: 3px;   border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;">dni</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




In modern browsers yes, it should be possible to use :focus on elements other than anchors, buttons, and other form elements. For example, a simple span should work...provided it has a tabindex attribute:


.morebuttonbox {
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, #ecd0ff, white 1px, transparent 0, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-color: #fcf8f8;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 260px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
}

.button {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  border: 1px ridge black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
  position: absolute
}

.contentbox2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 130px;
  width: 301px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 190px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.morebuttonbox:has(.button:focus)~.contentbox2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}
<div class="morebuttonbox">
  <span href="#" class="button" tabindex="1">
      more
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="contentbox2">
  <div class="byi">
    <span style="background-color:#ecd0ff;color:#7d6f85;padding:1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px; border-radius: 3px;   border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;">byi</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text ...

    <div class="dni">
      <span style="background-color:#ecd0ff;color:#7d6f85;padding:1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px; border-radius: 3px;   border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white #ae9cb9 #8b7c94 #7d6f85;">dni</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



